# Como capturar data retroativa

Tags: javascript, data, datepicker

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. Tenho que capturar duas datas, uma sendo o dia de hoje e outra sendo 15 dias para trás. Para pegar a data do dia eu fiz o seguinte.

```
function dateFormat() {
var initialDate = new Date(),
day = initialDate.getDate(),
month = initialDate.getMonth() + 1,
year = initialDate.getFullYear();
return (year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day; }
```

Consigo pegar a data de hoje sem problemas, mas como devo fazer para pegar uma data 15 dias atrás. Sendo que existe a diferença de dias entre os meses.

Obs o valor do **return** na função é devido a forma como devo enviar essa data ao servidor, pois ela deve ir como **YYYYMMDD**.

Comment: Vc quer pegar a data pra trás e fazer o que na função?

Comment: Eu tenho que pegar os dados de uma tabela que muda diariamente e estou criando um filtro que pega os dados dos últimos 15 dias.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função setDate para definir a data diminuindo os seus 15 dias, veja o exemplo

```
function dateFormat() {
  var initialDate = new Date();
  initialDate.setDate(initialDate.getDate() - 15);
  day = initialDate.getDate();
  month = initialDate.getMonth() + 1;
  year = initialDate.getFullYear();
  return (year * 10000) + (month * 100) + day; 
}
```

Comment: Está dando um retorno estranho. Fiz o teste assim, day = initialDate.setDate(initialDate.getDate() - 15), e ele deu isso no retorno do dia... 1511814481892

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações na resposta, veja se agora funciona para você

Comment: Consegui resolver de outra forma. Fiz uma variável dateOffset, para contar o tempo para trás, baseado nas horas
var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * 15; //15 dias
var initialDate = new Date();
initialDate.setTime(initialDate.getTime() - dateOffset);

Answer (score -1):

```
var campo = document.querySelector('#checkin');
```

// ATENÃ‡ÃƒO: toISOString() nÃ£o Ã© a melhor opÃ§Ã£o, veja explicaÃ§Ã£o abaixo
var hoje = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);

// DOMContentLoaded: assim que carregar a pÃ¡gina
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// seta a data mÃ­nima para o campo
campo.min = hoje;
});

// mostra mensagem de erro customizada (caso nÃ£o queira a mensagem padrÃ£o do browser)
campo.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
e.target.setCustomValidity(`A data nÃ£o pode ser anterior a ${hoje}`);
});
campo.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
e.target.setCustomValidity('');
e.target.checkValidity();
});

```
<input id="checkin" name="checkin" class="date-picker form-control" type="date" value="">
```